# How to shift this html body to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html page but the body is too close to the left. I would like to leave some margin from the left. In other words, I would like to shift the html body to the right.

The html code is as follows;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>head title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <h1>Test Page</h1>
      <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Column1</strong>
            </td>
            <td>Col1 data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Column1</strong>
            </td>
            <td>Col2 data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <form novalidate="" class="simple-form">PersonID

      <input type="text"  />    
      <BR><BR>
      name
      <input type="text" />    
      <BR><BR>

      <button ng-click="submit()" id="submit_btn">SUBMIT</button> 

      </form> 
      <br>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

What can I do to shift the html body slightly to the right so that it does not appear too close to the left side?

Comment: body{padding-left:20px;}

Comment: You need to use some CSS for that. A good css guide: [click here](http://www.cssbasics.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Bootstrap? You can center your content with a simple CSS code

```
body {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: So bootstrap will take care of the body distance to the border with width 800px.

Answer (score 4):

Inbetween your head tags add this:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!-- 

body {
   padding: 10px;
}

-->
</style>
```

That'll push everything inside the body tags by 10px. Change it to what looks best for you though. 10px might not be much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but if this is what you mean..

```
body {
    padding-left: 20px; 
}
```

or

```
body {
    margin-left: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this... add to the body tag

```html
<body style="margin-left:50px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

`<body style="margin-left: 50px">` should do the job.

You can read more on the CSS box-model [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) and here is a pretty [good tutorial](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/the-box-model-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 1):

Just insert this tag in

```
<style type="text/css"> 
body { padding-left:10px; } 
</style>
```

padding-left value can be adjusted as per your need !

Answer (score 1):

you can also get this done by..

**css**

```
body{
    width:95%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: it shifts the total content (body) a bit to center, so that it doesn't touch the left and right wall!!